# Type 'Statement' is not assignable to type 'any[]'

Tags: angular

I'm having trouble trying to figure out why I keep get this error:

```
C:/Users/zuberiaz/Documents/ECT/ECT2/ECT2/src/app/main-panels/result-display-panel/record-display/record-display.component.ts (89,103): Argument of type '(statements: Statement[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Statement) => void'.
```

Types of parameters 'statements' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'Statement' is not assignable to type 'Statement[]'.
      Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Statement'.

This is my component file:

```
statements: any[];
ngOnInit() {
    this.recordDisplayService.getStatementsBySource('8d71e58c-e56d-4782-b695-8d6bb87ace5e').subscribe(statements => {this.statements = statements;});
    this.politicalParties = [];
}
```

Service File:

```
//Fetch statements by source id
getStatementsByUrl = 'http://api/V1/Statement/QueryDocument?properties=all';
getStatementsBySource(sourceId: string): Observable<Statement> {
  return this.http.get(this.getStatementsByUrl + '/' + sourceId)
  .map(data =>  {return this.extractData(data);})
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a Statement class? Otherwise why you return Observable<Statement>?

Comment: Yes, I have a statement class

Comment: I think just change to Observable<Statement[]>. And, eventually, you can also do statements: Statement[];

Answer (score 1):

Your service class:

```
//Fetch statements by source id
getStatementsByUrl = 'http://api/V1/Statement/QueryDocument?properties=all';
getStatementsBySource(sourceId: string): Observable<Statement> {
  return this.http.get(this.getStatementsByUrl + '/' + sourceId)
  .map(data =>  {return this.extractData(data);})
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Appears to be returning one Statement. If you mean for it to get multiple Statements, then change the return type to this:

```
getStatementsBySource(sourceId: string): Observable<Statement[]>
```

If it does indeed return one statement, then you need to change your component code:

```
statement: Statement;
ngOnInit() {
    this.recordDisplayService.getStatementsBySource('8d71e58c-e56d-4782-b695-8d6bb87ace5e').subscribe(statement => {this.statement = statement;});
    this.politicalParties = [];
}
```